# How to get the values of the all objects of a large array and set them to the variables?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm newbie in PHP. I have to code the system like RSS Reader in this language. So I parsed XML files (which are RSS Feeds) and got a large array which has many sub-arrays. Since it is hard to explain what I need, I decided to add the example code. 
 As you see, there is an *`items`* in my large array and there are a lot of sub-array of *`items`* array, for example, *`[0]`*, *`[1]`*, *`[2]`*, *`[3]`* and so on. (I added to the examples just 2 ones of them - *`[0]`* and *`[1]`*)

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => First title
                    [alternate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => http://example-one.com/first-title/
                                )
                        )

                    [contents] => Array
                        (
                            [content] => First content
                        )
                    [author] => First author
                    [origin] => Array
                        (
                            [htmlUrl] => http://example-one.com
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                ( 
                    [title] => Second title
                    [alternate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => http://example-two.com/second-title/
                                )
                        )

                    [contents] => Array
                        (
                            [content] => Second content
                        )

                    [author] => Second author

                    [origin] => Array
                        (
                            [htmlUrl] => http://example-two.com
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So I need to get the values of the all objects in the output and set them to the variables in the loop. For example, the output of this array must be like this:

```
title = First title
href = http://example-one.com/first-title/
content = First content
author = First author
htmlUrl = example-one.com


title = Second title
href = http://example-two.com/second-title/
content = Second content
author = Second author
htmlUrl = example-two.com
```

Since, I'm beginner in PHP, it's hard to write the code of logic. If you have any idea for solving this problem, please answer.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [this link](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php/). It tells how to deal with arrays structured like a tree. Despite it may seem a bit advanced and complicated, try to understand it. Believe me, it's the best for you!

**EDIT**

```
$a = array(); // This is the array that we will store the values

function traverse($array)
{
    global $a;

    $results = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value) { 

         if (is_array($value)) { 
            $results = traverse($value); // This is where you make the function recursive and go deeper in the array
         } else { 
            $a[] = $key . ' = ' . $value; // This is where you store the values
         }

    }

    return $a;
}
// You just call the function like this.
$ret = traverse($arr);

echo implode('<br>', $ret);
```

Comment: but this article is hard for beginner, is there not any article or function for lazybones ? =)

Comment: i just need to get values of the objects and set it to the variables. isn't it possible with foreach function ?

Comment: @John hang on, I'll try to figure something in a few mins.

Comment: @John Really sorry for the delay. Had the occupy with something else. Hope now that helps :)

Comment: thanx very- very much. well, it definitly returns the output which I showed. but I wrote that, I need to set the values of the objects in the loop. for example, $title = ... , $author = .. what about that ?

Comment: i need to write the values to the database, that is why, i asked

Comment: @John that is not possible since you will override $title variable each time the $key variable sets the $title. One variable can only hold one value. Only arrays can have different values which means you'd have to create arrays for each variable you wish.

Comment: @John do you use pdo class or mysql_query to connect your database?

Comment: for example, i need only the title and href to add the database

Comment: @John Well, I believe that you're doing something wrong because inserting to a database should not be that complicated. I was writing a code for you but then I thought that there should be a more PHP way to accomplish your task. Tell me how you develop that array.

Comment: @John, By the way, if you know that the order will be always like that, just travel the main array and look for the items you need. for instance, $array[0]['title'] will give you the first title, and $array[0]['alternate']['href'] will give you first the href.

Comment: I got this array via API. it was in json format, then I parsed it and got this array